# Dygraph Annotations

Tags: javascript, annotations, dygraphs

I would update  my Annotations, i become the data as Javascript string.
I read the annotations from a MYSQL database, but i Transfer during update the Chart the new data as a javastring.

Why does this not run?

```
var dat = "[{series: 'AKKU [V]', x: Date.parse('2014/07/06 12:58:12'), shortText: 'A', text: 'Akku geladen'}]";
```

graphdiv2.setAnnotations(dat);

This runs.

```
graphdiv2.setAnnotations([{series: 'AKKU [V]', x: Date.parse('2014/07/06 12:58:12'), shortText: 'A', text: 'Akku geladen'}]);
```

Can help me somebody?

this runs althoug, with an php string, but i can´t use an php string.

```
graphdiv2.setAnnotations([<?php echo $aaa ?>]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i read and write the annotations to a mysql database.
here is the code. 
My Problem is in the first blog.

```
<?php
```

include("xxx.php");
$aaa = "[             ";

$annotation_data  = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(xval,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') AS xval1, xval, series, shortText, text
                        FROM ".$database_anno." ORDER BY xval  ") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($annotation_data))
  {
  $text = str_replace("\r\n", "
", $row['text']);       // eingebaute Umbrüche ausbessern

$aaa = " " .$aaa. "{series: '".$row[series]."', x: Date.parse('".$row[xval1]."'), shortText: '".$row[shortText]."', text: '" .$text."'}," ;

```
}
$aaa = "" .$aaa. "]";
//echo $aaa;
```

?>

var dataphp =  ;